# Create local copy of remote Maven repository using publishToMavenLocal

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I have a remote dependency in my Android project that I would like to modify (replace one of its dependencies by a more recent one).

This basically means that I would like to edit the `.pom` file of this library.
I don't have access to the code of the library.

I have this line in my build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.acme:the-sdk:1.1.0@aar'
```

It seems that the `publishToMavenLocal` task would be a solution: it would create a local copy of `the-sdk`, including the `.pom` and `.aar` files.
I would then modify the `.pom` file, and add `mavenLocal()` as 1st item in the list of repos.

I'm not too familiar with Gradle.

**How can I use `publishToMavenLocal` (or another tool) to create this local copy of the library?**

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add the "more recent one" to your own project, so you effecively overwrite the dependency of your dependency?

Comment: @JFMeier It would probably be the best option in a more "standard" situation, but in my case, the `acme` dependency uses a "repackaged" version of the public library I want to override. So adding the up-to-date dependency to my `build.gradle` creates conflicts.

Comment: By "repackaged" you mean that they changed the groupId or artifactId?

Comment: Yes, they changed both the groupId (from `com.facebook.android` to `com.acme.partner`) and artifactId (from `audience-network-sdk` to `facebook`)

Comment: In Maven, I would explicitly exclude the "facebook" dependency of your dependency and add the "replacement" dependency to your project. This would all be possible in the pom of your project without manipulating the acme project. I guess that Gradle offers you similar features, but I am not fluent enough in Gradle to tell you.

Comment: You're right, it's actually that simple! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

As JFMeier suggested, I don't need to modify the acme project.

I only need to tell Gradle to exclude the dependency (so I can include it myself in the desired version).

```
implementation ('com.acme.the-sdk:1.1.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
    exclude module: 'facebook'
}

implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.1'
```